# How do I align all my div's in one line?

Tags: html, css

I've looked at a bunch of websites, but none of them worked for me. I'm probably missing something really simple.

```
#container {
  width:100%;
}

#one {
  background-color:blue;
  width:20%;
  height:50%;
}

#two {
  background-color:green;
  width:20%;
  height:50%;
}

#three {
  background-color:yellow;
  width:20%;
  height:50%;
}

#four {
  background-color:orange;
  width:20%;
  height:50%;
}

#five {
  background-color:red;
  width:20%;
  height:50%;
}
```

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

It doesn't display a lot, which I suspect is because of the height:50%...
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please provide some screenshots of what you get, and make what you want (ish) in paint or another editor.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't put an actual picture, I didn't have a high enough reputation

Comment: Next time, link one on imgur.

Comment: I did. I edited it

Comment: Ooh, it automagically embedded it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code a bit but this should output what you are looking for.

You display the divs inline, and position them relatively with a slightly negative margin so that they take up 20% of the width each.

In a comment you mentioned you want to "make it exactly 50% tall", so you need to give the body `100%` height, then set the divs to have `50%` height:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: -2px;
}
#one {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#two {
  background-color: green;
}
#three {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#four {
  background-color: orange;
}
#five {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">

</div>

<div id="two">

</div>

<div id="three">

</div>

<div id="four">
</div>

<div id="five">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add float left to each id in your container. This is a truncated version, no need to add the same css to each of your separate ids.

```
#container #one, #container #two, #container #three, #container #four, #container #five {
 float:left;
}
```

or you can use display inline block

```
#container #one, #container #two, #container #three, #container #four, #container #five {
     display:inline-block;
    }
```

To center the divs if any space is left over you can add text align center to ensure the divs in your container are centered properly. This only works when using display block inline on your container.

```
#container {
         text-align:center;
        }
```

Comment: float:left; is the route I always go, because it handles wrapping very nicely, especially if you can guarantee the div sizes with CSS (which, of course, is very easy).

Comment: Didn't display anything... Thanks anyways

Comment: Can you show an example of it not displaying using my method? I would be glad to assist in making it work.

Answer (score 2):

To put all the divs in the same line 
use

```
display:inline-block;
```

if want to show divs in next line, 
use

```
display:block;
```

default is set to block;

```css
#container {
width:100%;
  
}
#one,#two,#three,#four,#five{
width:20%;
height:50%;
}
#one {
background-color:blue;
display:inline-block;
}

#two {
background-color:green;
display:inline-block;
}
#three {
background-color:yellow;
  display:inline-block;
}
#four {
background-color:orange;
}
#five {
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="one">
    One
   </div>
   <div id="two">
     Two
   </div>
   <div id="three">
     Three
   </div>
  <div id="four">
     four
   </div>
  <div id="five">
     five
   </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Same thing, doesn't display anything

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if that's what you're asking but maybe you just need

```
div{float:right;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
#container div {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
}
#element-1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#element-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
#element-3 {
  background-color: pink;
}
#element-4 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#element-5 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="element-1"></div>
  <div id="element-2"></div>
  <div id="element-3"></div>
  <div id="element-4"></div>
  <div id="element-5"></div>
</div>
```

I have helped in some way

Comment: That worked, but is there a way to make it exactly 50% tall? Because I want it to be about the same on any device... Thanks anyways :D

Comment: @SenpaiSaitama There's another way yes. I did a little update on css example above.

Comment: It didn't really change anything but the border and made it shorter than before lol. Thanks anyways